# Create mind map of mongodb objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to make something like mind map from model Branches, which have "parent" and "children" value. It looks like :

```
Branches = [{
 children: {},
 _id: String,
 parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Branch' }
}]
```

And i want to get something like :

```
[
 {
    "_id": "599c1f79f339dc3991d8250a",
    "name": "Robert",
    "children": [
        {
            "_id": "599c1f82f339dc3991d8250b",
            "name": "Robert 1",
            "parent": "599c1f79f339dc3991d8250a",
            "children": [
                {
                    "_id": "599c1f8ff339dc3991d8250c",
                    "name": "Robert 2",
                    "parent": "599c1f82f339dc3991d8250b",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "_id": "599c2b7373a7d43e5205af1f",
                            "name": "Robert 4",
                            "parent": "599c1f8ff339dc3991d8250c",
                            "__v": 0,
                            "shareholder": [],
                            "createdDate": "2017-08-22T13:02:43.290Z",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "__v": 0,
                    "shareholder": [],
                    "createdDate": "2017-08-22T12:11:59.230Z"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "599c1f9df339dc3991d8250d",
                    "name": "Robert 3",
                    "parent": "599c1f82f339dc3991d8250b",
                    "children": [],
                    "__v": 0,
                    "shareholder": [],
                    "createdDate": "2017-08-22T12:12:13.156Z"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0,
            "shareholder": [],
            "createdDate": "2017-08-22T12:11:46.938Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "parent": null,
    "shareholder": [],
    "createdDate": "2017-08-22T12:11:37.005Z"
}
```

]"

If one object have value parent " 1 " , branch with _id : "1" must have him inside children object. My code now is :

```
Branch.find((err, foundedBranches) => {

 function createTree(branch) {
  function inner(parent) {
      return branch.filter(x => x.parent === parent)
              .map(x => {
                  x.children = inner(x._id)
                  return x
              })
  }
  return inner(null)
}
 let formated = createTree(branches)
 res.json(formated)
```

If You know how can I resolve it, please help :/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this - you will get childs for every entry

```
// All items from database
const dataFromDatabase = // ...

// For each item, go and look for childrens
const finalMap = dataFromDatabase.map((x) => {
  children: this.getChildren(dataFromDatabase, x._id),
  _id: x._id,
  // ...
});
```

---

```
// Get all children and for theses children go for children aswell (recursive)...
getChildren(all, id) {
  return all.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    if (x.parent === id) {
      return [
        ...tmp,
        {
          children: this.getChildren(all, x._id),
          _id: x._id,
          // ...
        },
      ];
    }

    return tmp;
  }, []);
}
```

---

If you want to entries to only appear once, at start filter the entries to get only heads (entries that have no, parent)

```
dataFromDatabase.filter(x => !x.parent).map((x) => {
```